# Calculate Solubility

Tags: solubility, alcohols, nitro-compounds

So I've been looking at some chemistry processes and I was trying to conclude how they got the numbers they got. How would I go about calculating the solubility of Phenyl-2-nitropropene in Isopropyl Alcohol?

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be calculated **theoretically** and has to be done **practically**

It is measured in terms of the maximum amount(usually moles) of solute dissolved in a solvent at equilibrium